# How to determine if computer has TPM (Trusted Platform Module) available

Tags: linux, security, tpm

Wanting to play around with [Trusted Platform Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) stuff, I installed [TrouSerS](http://trousers.sourceforge.net/) and tried to start [`tcsd`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tcsd), but I got this error:

```
TCSD TDDL ERROR: Could not find a device to open!
```

However, my kernel has multiple TPM modules loaded:

```
# lsmod | grep tpm
tpm_crb                16384  0
tpm_tis                16384  0
tpm_tis_core           20480  1 tpm_tis
tpm                    40960  3 tpm_tis,tpm_crb,tpm_tis_core
```

So, how do I determine if my computer is lacking TPM vs TrouSerS having a bug?

Neither [`dmidecode`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode) nor [`cpuid`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cpuid) output anything about "tpm" or "trust".  Looking in `/var/log/messages`, on the one hand I see `rngd: /dev/tpm0: No such file or directory`, but on the other hand I see `kernel: Initialise system trusted keyrings` and according to [this kernel doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/keys-trusted-encrypted.txt) trusted keys use TPM.

**EDIT**: My computer's BIOS setup menus mention nothing about TPM.

Also, looking at `/proc/keys`:

```
# cat /proc/keys 
******** I--Q---     1 perm 1f3f0000     0 65534 keyring   _uid_ses.0: 1
******** I--Q---     7 perm 3f030000     0     0 keyring   _ses: 1
******** I--Q---     3 perm 1f3f0000     0 65534 keyring   _uid.0: empty
******** I------     2 perm 1f0b0000     0     0 keyring   .builtin_trusted_keys: 1
******** I------     1 perm 1f0b0000     0     0 keyring   .system_blacklist_keyring: empty
******** I------     1 perm 1f0f0000     0     0 keyring   .secondary_trusted_keys: 1
******** I------     1 perm 1f030000     0     0 asymmetri Fedora kernel signing key: 34ae686b57a59c0bf2b8c27b98287634b0f81bf8: X509.rsa b0f81bf8 []
```

Comment: The TPM is typically described by the ACPI tables set up by the bios. If `dmesg | grep -w tpm` doesn't give messages about initializing a tpm then you haven't got one which is recognised by the kernel. Most laptops and desktops don't have TPMs, they are pretty standard on machines sold as servers (i.e. things big enough to run IPMI), and also on chromebooks where they are part of the security story.

Comment: To play, ibm developed a [soft tpm](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ibmswtpm/) you can compile and run, and there is also [this](https://github.com/PeterHuewe/tpm-emulator) easier to use emulator.

Comment: all replies here look at some file somewhere called \*tpm\*, but how can i get direct info about the tpm hardware installed?  A file might be misplaced, or maybe it is refering to a "software" tpm-emulator !!?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

TPMs don't necessarily appear in the ACPI tables, but the modules do print a message when they find a supported module; for example

```
[  134.026892] tpm_tis 00:08: 1.2 TPM (device-id 0xB, rev-id 16)
```

So `dmesg | grep -i tpm` is a good indicator.

The definitive indicator is your firmware's setup tool: TPMs involve ownership procedures which are managed from the firmware setup. If your setup doesn't mention anything TPM-related then you don't have a TPM.

TPMs were initially found in servers and business laptops (and ChromeBooks, as explained by [icarus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/194382/icarus)), and were rare in desktops or "non-business" laptops; that’s changed over the last few years, and Windows 11 requires a TPM now. Anything supporting Intel TXT has a TPM.

Comment: Year 2020 update: Most newly manufactured PCs, even consumer models, are now shipping with a TPM. Microsoft [officially recommends them](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/tpm/tpm-recommendations) in all new PCs, and a growing number of Windows features require it.

Comment: My SLIMBOOK Pro X 15 (on kernel 5.13) does not show anything when I do "dmesg | grep -i tpm" however "cat /sys/class/tpm/tpm*/tpm_version_major" says "2".

Answer (score 31):

Also can also detect it via sysfs:

```
[ -d $(ls -d /sys/kernel/security/tpm* 2>/dev/null | head -1) ] && \
    echo "TPM available" || echo "TPM missing"
```

And since kernel **5.6** (commit [7084eddf6be9 tpm: Add tpm_version_major sysfs file](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=7084eddf6be94e73f8298c1a28078b91536f2975)), version can be detected with sysfs file:

```
$ cat /sys/class/tpm/tpm*/tpm_version_major
1
```

NOTE: some TPM don't export sysfs (firmware bug).

Other way is to check for `/dev/tpm0` or `/dev/tpmrm0`. All TPM devices should have `/dev/tpm0`. `/dev/tpmrm0` is only for TPM 2.0, but it was added in v4.12-rc1 ([fdc915f7f719 tpm: expose spaces via a device link /dev/tpmrm](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=fdc915f7f71939ad5a3dda3389b8d2d7a7c5ee66)):

```bsh
[ -c /dev/tpmrm0 ] && echo "TPM 2.0" # since v4.12-rc1

[ -c /dev/tpm0 ] && echo "TPM 1.2 or 2.0"
```

Comment: First check fails but last two succeed on my system.

Comment: The first check returns always true, I'd suggest using something like: `[ ! -z "$(ls /dev/tpm* 2>/dev/null)" ] && echo "TPM available" || echo "TPM missing"`